# Using ASP <% .... %> Tags

Tags: asp.net

I have been searching for this for quite a while and couldn't find a solution...

I have my aspx file and in it a asp:SqlDataSource, where I want to get values which are equal to the Request.QueryString["key"]. I have defined a parameter for it but I can't find the right syntax to set the value.

Currently it is looking like this:

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="courseID" DefaultValue="<%= Request.QueryString["course_name"]
</SelectParameters>
```

where I always get the error, it is not well formed. What is the correct syntax, and is there an article how you use this <%.. %> commands?

Comment: Can you show an example of your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's [an MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fy30at8h.aspx) that goes over what each tag is and what it does.  Probably using `<%...%>` is not correct, as that's just a code tag. You want `<%=...%>` or `<%:...%>` which actually write values to the page.

But!  Actually, if I'm reading what your problem is correctly, you want neither of those.  For a SqlDataSource to pull in a query string value, you want to add a `<SelectParameters>` tag to the datasource, then add a `<QueryStringParameter>` to that.

Edit:

Yep, looking at the edit you just made, you definitely want a [QueryStringParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.querystringparameter.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `<%=` within high-level asp controls.  That construct writes directly to the output buffer, whereas the controls need to be processed first. In other words, rather than processing your `<%=` before expanding the control, it must first expand the control before it can process your `<%=`.  They are at different levels of abstraction.

To do what you want to accomplish, rather than a plain `<asp:Parameter>` use an `<asp:QueryStringParameter>`.  This will allow you to set the key you want to use from the query string.